# Using WebAPI for everything including web site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, oauth, asp.net-web-api

I am building a web site, and have created an API for it using WebAPI. The API is secured using OAuth v1 using DotNetOpenAuth and all is working fine with an iPhone app calling into the API. I would like to go back and make the pertinent parts of the web use the API too so that evrything always goes through the API.

The part I am slightly confused about though is if I make my website login go through the API,  set up the web site as an OAuth Consumer, get an OAuth token for the current user, should I then in the web site code make a http call into WebAPI on the same box to call the API passing my OAuth token? (in the HTTP Auth header)

It seems like quite an inefficient way to get the web site to call the API as all calls require the server side to make a HTTP call as well, doesn't sound particularly scalable to me? I am not sure of the alternatives though given I want to use OAuth to secure the API.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question and keeps coming up (since you clearly realise the overhead of having another network-bound hop):

## Do I need to consume my own API in my ASP.NET MVC or bypass API and go straight to the business logic?

I have tried to explain this in a [blog post](http://byterot.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/api-layer-and-its-responsibilities-rest-viewpoint-webapi-csds-aspnetwebapi.html) (towards the end of the post). However, in short: **it depends**. If your API and MVC site are part of the same application, then they sit next to each other as they are both the **Presentation Layer** - as I explain in the post. If, however, your API is the presentation layer of an SOA service and used by several clients including your MVC site, then yes it has to be separate.

In your case, I am inclined to put the MVC *side by side* your Web API - accessing the same business layer. And I believe this also fixes the OAuth issue you are having.